# How do I search for a "-" in a field value in kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana

Here is the mapping for this field:

```
"username": {
  "type": "text",
  "norms": false,
  "fields": {
    "keyword": {
      "type": "keyword"
    }
  }
},
```

I have a field that occasionally has the value of "-":
[image]

I clicked "filter for value" and this is the filter it created:[image]

But when I do searches for this value it says not results found.

How do I escape the "-"?

I tried "\-" but no dice

I tried check if the value "exists" as suggested but this also returns 0 results: [image]

Also tried `!(_exists_:"username")` in the kibana search bar and that also returns 0 results.

Also running `(_exists_:"username")` included docs with and without a value for the username field

I also tried this which returns 0 results:

```
(_missing_:"username")
```

Comment: In Kibana `-` represents that field has no value typically it is null. If you want to search all docs which have `username` value as `null` then you can use `exists` query.

Comment: what would that query look like?

Comment: `GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": {
                "exists": {
                    "field": "username"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}`

Comment: that query doesn't seem to work- it returns 0 results

Comment: Can you provide complete query you executed?

Comment: so im running this in the kibana discover pane. Added a screenshot to the post

Comment: If you are doing it from kibana search bar use this `!(_exists_:"username") `

Comment: !(_exists_:"username") from search bar also returns 0 results.

Comment: Its not `!(exists:"username") ` but `!( _exists_ :"username") ` leading and trailing `_`(underscore) should be there around `exists` keyword.

Comment: sorry, just forgot to wrap it in code blocks, look at the edit to my post, I did it with underscores, still returns nothing

Comment: Ok. Can you look at your `JSON` representation of document and check whether `username` field present and what value it holds?

Comment: in json the field is there but its just blank.

Comment: Can you provide mapping of `username` field? and what version of ES are you using?

Comment: I added my mapping for that field in the post

Comment: This should definitely work: `username.keyword: "-"` . OR provide this in filter  `{
  "term": {
    "username.keyword": "-"
  }
}` . Both are equivalent.

Comment: yesss thank you that works. Why the hell is going on here? Is there a good doc that explains why this works the way it does? You should add that as an answer by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your `username` field is of `text` type and analyzed with [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html#analysis-standard-analyzer), the inverted index will have no tokens for `username` where as `username.keyword` is of `keyword` type it will have the exact value `-` in inverted index.

You can search it in following ways:

1. **From Kibana search bar:**

   `username.keyword: "-"`
2. **From Kibana filter:**

   `{
     "term": {
       "username.keyword": "-"
     }
   }`
3. **From Sense plugin:**

   `GET _search
   {
     "query": {
       "term": {
         "username.keyword": "-"
       }
     }
   }`